# Custom string validation with Joi.js

Tags: validation, joi

I have an input in my API and I need to validate it and see if it is one the two string that I desire. Is there way to validate the string with Joi.js

```
type DummyValidatorInput = {
  firstInput: string;
  secondInput: string;
}

export const DummyValidator = (
  input: DummyValidatorInput,
): Joi.ValidationResult => {
  return Joi.object({
    firstInput: Joi.string().min(5).max(64).required(),
    secondInput: Joi.string().required()
  }).validate(input);
};
```

I want to validate that if the `secondInput` is `customerTypeOne` string or `customerTypeTwo` string, is this possible with Joi?
Any idea or suggestion is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [any.valid](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyvalidvalues---aliases-equal)?

```js
secondInput: Joi.string().valid('customerTypeOne', 'customerTypeTwo').required()
```